# Converting rows to columns in a timesheet scenario

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create an employment timesheet for contractors.  I need to output a table with a date column and have the flexibility of a variable number of pay rates.

The pay rates are in a table called "RATES" and these need to become columns of the output table:

```
RATEID    PROJECTID   RATENAME   RATEOFPAY
1         1           Normal     1000
2         1           Double     2000
3         1           Special    2500
4         2           Flatrate   1000
5         3           Rateone    1000
6         3           Rate2      1500
```

I already have a function that generates dates between ranges:

```
SELECT IndividualDate FROM DateRange('03-01-16', '03-30-16') as DATESINRANGE
```

This outputs

```
IndividualDate
2016-03-01 00:00:00.000
2016-03-02 00:00:00.000
thru
2016-03-30 00:00:00.000
```

I have a 3rd table that contains data about when these contractors worked, the rate and number of hours (they may not work every day):

```
dateworked    projectid  rateid     hoursworked
2016-03-02    1          2          5
2016-03-02    1          3          2
```

What I want is to output a table that shows every day of the month for PROJECTID=1  like this:

```
Dates        Normal     Double    Special
2016-03-01   0          0         0
2016-03-02   0          5         2
2016-03-03   0          0         0
etc...
```

I've looked at examples with PIVOT, but am not sure if they apply in this scenario as the examples used aggregates.  I'd really appreciate help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try following solution:

```
DECLARE @ProjectID INT = 1, @FromDt DATE = '2016-03-01', @ToDt DATE = '2016-03-31'

DECLARE @RateColumns NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'', @SqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAXW);

SELECT @RateColumns = @RateColumns + N', ' + QUOTENAME(RateName)
FROM dbo.PayRates a
WHERE a.ProjectID = @ProjectID

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Internal error: there is no rates for current project', 16, 1)
END

SET @RateColumns = STUFF(@RateColumns, 1, 2, N'')

SET @SqlStatement = N'
SELECT b.*
FROM (
    SELECT IndividualDate, HoursWorked, RateName
    FROM dbo.DateRange(@FromDt, @ToDt) f
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ThirdTable tt ON ff.IndividualDate = tt.DateWorked 
    AND tt.ProjectID = @ProjectID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.PayRates pr ON tt.RateID = pr.RateID
    AND pr.ProjectID = tt.ProjectID -- Is it necessary ?
) a
PIVOT( SUM(HoursWorked) FOR RateName IN (' + @RateColumns + N') b'

EXEC sp_executesql 
    @SqlStatement, 
    N'@ProjectID INT, @FromDt DATE, @ToDt DATE', 
    @ProjectID, @FromDt, @ToDt
```

Comment: I think my SQL skills moved on a lot today learning from the above.  My timesheet is now working, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See if this will get you started. It's surely not the most ideal solution but hopefully it can help

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Rates') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Rates
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RatePivot') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #RatePivot
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DatesWorked') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #DatesWorked

CREATE TABLE #Rates (RATEID INT, PROJECTID INT, RATENAME VARCHAR(24), RATEOFPAY MONEY)

INSERT INTO #Rates(RATEID,PROJECTID,RATENAME,RATEOFPAY)VALUES
(1,1,'Normal',1000),
(2,1,'Double',2000),
(3,1,'Special',2500),
(4,2,'Flatrate',1000),
(5,3,'Rateone',1000),
(6,3,'Rate2',1500)

create table #DatesWorked(dateworked datetime,projectid int, rateid int, hoursworked int)
insert into #DatesWorked (dateworked,projectid,rateid,hoursworked) values
('2016-03-02',1,2,5),
('2016-03-02',1,3,2)

select * into #RatePivot from 
(select PROJECTID, RATEID, RATENAME, RATEOFPAY from #Rates) as r
pivot
(max(RATEOFPAY) for RATENAME in ([Normal],[Double],[Special],[Flatrate],[Rateone],[Rate2])) as p

select * from #RatePivot

select
    d.dateworked,
    count(r.Normal) as Normal,
    count(r.[Double]) as [Double],
    count(r.Special) as Special,
    count(r.Flatrate) as Flatrate,
    count(r.Rateone) as Rateone,
    count(r.Rate2) as Rate2
from 
    #DatesWorked d
    inner join #RatePivot r on r.RATEID = d.rateid and r.PROJECTID = d.projectid
where d.projectid = 1
group by d.dateworked
```